# Introduce dependence between predicted residuals even the true residuals are independent?

Tags: causality

I have been reading this paper called *[Distinguishing cause from effect using observational data: methods and benchmarks](http://arxiv.org/abs/1412.3773)*.

On page 13, the author claims the following:

> **Lemma 7**: Given a joint density $p(x,y)$ of two random variables $X,Y$ such that the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}(Y|X=x)$ is well-defined for all $x$ and measurable. Then, $p(x,y)$ satisfies a bivariate additive noise model $X\to Y$ if and only if $E_Y := Y - \mathbb{E}(Y|X)$ has finite mean and is independent of $X$.

After that, the author claims that one way to test the independence of the residuals $Y - \mathbb{E}(Y|X)$ and $X$, one can do the following:

> By regressing $Y$ on $X$ using the training data $\mathcal{D}_N$, an estimate $\hat{f}_Y$ for the regression function $x\mapsto \mathbb{E}(Y|X=x)$ is obtained. Then, an independence test is used to estimate whether the predicted residuals are independent of the input, i.e., whether $(y - \hat{f}_Y (X))\perp X$ using test data $(\bf x',y')$.

These all make sense to me. But I am confused by page 14:

> There is a caveat, however: under the null hypothesis that $p(x,y)$ indeed satisfies an ANM, the error in the estimated residuals may introduce a dependence between the predicted residuals $\bf \hat{e'}_Y := y' - \hat{f}_Y (x')$ and $\bf \hat{x'}$, even if the true residuals $\bf y' - \mathbb{E}(Y | X=x')$ are independent of $\bf x'$.

Why could that be the case?